# How do i reference different objects with the same variable name in a loop

Tags: java, loops, object, reference

NOT ALLOWED TO USE ARRAYS

How do i make it so i can change what object the **song** variable references with every loop.

`private Song song1, song2, song3, song4;`

```
public Album()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        song1 = new Song();
        song2 = new Song();
        song3 = new Song();
        song4 = new Song();
    }
```

```
public void setSongs()
    {
      for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        var song = song + i;
        System.out.print("Enter a song name: "); String songName = console.nextLine(); song.setName(songName);
        System.out.print("Enter the artist: "); String songArtist = console.nextLine(); song.setArtist(songArtist);
        System.out.print("Enter duration time in seconds: "); int songDuration = console.nextInt(); song.setDuration(songDuration);
        System.out.println("Enter from genres: \n [1] Rock \n [2] Pop \n [3] Hip-hop \n [4] Bossa Nova "); int songGenre = console.nextInt();
        switch (songGenre) {
          case 1:
            System.out.println("Genre selected : Rock");
            song.setGenre("Rock");
            break;
          case 2:
            System.out.println("Genre selected : Pop");
            song.setGenre("Pop");
            break;
          case 3:
            System.out.println("Genre selected : Hip-hop");
            song.setGenre("Hip-hop");
            break;
          case 4:
            System.out.println("Genre selected : Bossa Nova");
            song.setGenre("Bossa Nova");
            break;
        }
        console.nextLine();
        System.out.println(songName + " by " + songArtist + " has been added to " + name);
      }
    }
```

I am aware that the above code does not work but it is an example of what i am trying to do.

Comment: store them in a list or array, and iterate over them as: for ( Song song: mySongs)

Comment: As to why: you can't dynamically create variable names during runtime.

Comment: What about something like this? `var song = (i == 1 ? song1 : (i == 2 ? song2 : (i == 3 ? song3 : song4)))`

Comment: Thanks allot man that seams to work. I am quite a noob at java so i will have to go look at what all the stuff you wrote means. But thanks heaps!